# How to unload UIViewcontroller from memory?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

My app structure (targeting iOS 6.1 w/ARC):

*Intro View Controller* ->presents-> *Main Menu View Controller* ->presents-> *Stuff View Controller*

The *Intro View Controller* is shown only once, on app launch. The user is able to jump back to the *Main Menu View Controller* (currently achieved by using `dismissViewControllerAnimated:`).

But how do I get rid of the *Intro View Controller* still lingering in memory?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a different structure to do this. Make MainMenuViewController the root view controller of the window, and present IntroViewController modally from MainMenuViewController's viewDidAppear method with no animation. This will make IntroViewController the first thing the user sees. Dismiss it when you're done with it, and it will be deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UINavigationController`'s `setViewControllers:` to manually alter the view controller stack after the launch view controller disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Why not configure your hierarchy so that when it is necessary to present intro view controller, it gets presented from main menu view controller without any animation so that it appears to have been the first view controller you interact with.

Then you can dismiss it to get back to main menu view controller thus freeing it from memory. From here you can present stuff view controller as you normally would.